# Trying to call send function in web3 and it returns an error => Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: unknown account

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I am trying to call a method of smart contract which is a write method

```
const temp = await goin_contract.methods
    .increaseAllowance("0xEd61D93121D0b8435f9D2AaCB7dea0A3D067c4E2", stakeValue)
    .send({ from: account });
```

However whenever I call this method it returns this error

```
*Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: unknown account
    at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:28:1)
    at index.js:302:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange*
```

Read methods of smart-contract are working perfectly.

I have read some articles on how to solve this error but cant find a definite solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which account do you use to send the transaction?

Comment: the account we get from  { const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",}); }

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Metamask provider instead of node URL `const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);`